# Meteor Cordova input field white band above soft keyboard

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, user-accounts, meteoric

I am using ionic sign in and sign up screens from http://useraccounts.meteor.com/

When I am testing it on my nexus 5 I see a big white band above the onscreen keyboard as shown below

Without Keyboard
[image: Without keyboard]
With Keyboard
[image: with keyboard]

Comment: on further investigation whenever keyboard pops-up body is added **keyboard-open** class and css style added which will change bottom of the input form `<body class="keyboard-open">`  and `<div class="content overflow-scroll has-header" style="bottom: 248px;">` this extra 248px is the resulting white band

Answer (score 1):

Found solution at https://github.com/meteoric/meteor-ionic/issues/89
problem is with ionic-keyboard intended for ios

TL;DR
add the following code to css

```
.content.overflow-scroll {
bottom: 0px !important;
}
```